# How do Haredim view Modern Orthodoxy?

Tags: orthodox

I am curious if there is any documented opinion piece by any universally recognized Haredi gadol (universally recognized as being Haredi or *right wing*), about modern orthodoxy as an ideology. Also is there a clear and documented divide between different sects in regards to their views.

I am not asking for anyone's personal opinions about *Modern Orthodox*, rather if anyone knows of anything clear, and universal. (and no, I am not discussing "Open Orthodoxy")

Comment: The answer will be "It depends", as "modern orthodox' is a very wide range of views in practice.

Comment: And because Haredi is also a range @orangesandlemons

Comment: Your average Israeli  Haredi will answer _MO Rabbis? I've never heard of any!_ (Based on experience - my Dati colleges reference their Rabbis and I've never heard of any of them.)

Comment: The question is WHAT IS THE OPINION of chareidim! of course it is opinion based! that's like saying "what's the opinion of Rashi" is opinion based! duh!

Comment: @mbloch can we get an idea of why this is still on hold, the question now precludes any opinion based answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is from [R. Aharon Kotler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Kotler)'s eulogy for [R. Yitzchak Ze'ev Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Zev_Soloveitchik). I believe R. Kotler fits the designation of a "universally recognized Haredi gadol".

**[Mishnas Rabbi Aharon Vol. III p. 216](https://a.disquscdn.com/uploads/mediaembed/images/2756/4952/original.jpg)**

> ועל כל אלה נוספו עתה כאלה המתקראים אוטודוקסים מודרניים הטוענים ששיטתם
>   היא שיטת היהדות הנאמנה ודרכם היא דרך התורה המסורה לנו מדור דור אלא שהם
>   מכניסים קצת מודרניזציה ושינויים קלים חסרי משמעות כדי לחבב את דרך התורה
>   על ההמון האמת היא שהנקודה הקטנה הזאת היא היא נקודת הרפורם והיא לב לבה
>   של ההתרחקות הגדולה מדרך התורה והיראה בדורות האחרונים הם משנים הנהגות
>   ומסלפים יסודות והם משנים את בתי הכנסת מקדשי מעט ממה שצריך להיות מלבד
>   זה בהתחברם בצורה אירגונית עם הכופרים והרפורמים ה"ה מאשרים שמה
>   שהרפורמים קורים בית כנסת ראוי להקרא כך ומה שהם קורים רב ראוי להיקרא כך
>   ויש בזה חורבן גדול
>
> And on top of all these, they have now added those who are called
>   "Modern Orthodox", who claim that their way is the way of faithful
>   Judaism and their path is the path of the Torah that was given over to
>   us from generation to generation, except that they add in a little
>   "modernization" and small changes without significant import in order
>   to endear the path of the Torah to the populace. The truth is that
>   this small point is the exact point of Reform, and is the heart of the
>   great distancing from the path of Torah and fear in the last
>   generations. They change practices and they distort fundamentals, and
>   they change the synagogues – the mini sanctuaries –  slightly from how
>   they must be. Aside from this, with their connection in an
>   organizational manner with the heretics and Reform they are certifying
>   that that which the Reform call a synagogue is worthy to be called
>   that, and that which they call rabbi is fitting to be called that. And
>   this contains a great destruction.

Comment: Was Rav Yoshe Ber Also their at his uncles eulogy? Can one believe something not written by Rav Aharon Kotler himself? Was he referring to only specific comunities wo were particularly assimilated? Was he also refering some to Chareidi  communities who  have members with there own differences e.g Tznius problems? has nothing changed in nearly  60 years since Rav Yitzchak Zeev died?

Comment: @user15464 You're right that this doesn't appear to apply to all modern Modern Orthodox Jews, but that's a weakness in the question not in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Netziv's Meshiv Davar I:44 (c. 1881) has the Netziv rejecting those to his right who feel that Jews must always be divided into "left, right, and center." He says that whatever issues exist, the community must work together, e.g. to arrange for kosher secular studies, rather than leaving people to their own devices.

Mind you, not clear I'd call Netziv "Haredi" by today's standards.

Comment: The Netziv is totally _not_ Haredi by today's standards. As brought down in the (now banned) ArtScroll sefer, _My Uncle the Netziv_, he would read newspapers on Shabbos. (Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to fling dirt on the Netziv, I'm just bringing to light a biographical fact in order to show that most likely Haredim today wouldn't consider him "Haredi".)

Comment: @ezra it's a misconception that my uncle the netziv is banned. All that happened was a school sent out free copies and subsequently sent a letter apologizing and saying the book doesn't reflect their values. Artscroll wouldn't continue to sell a banned book.

Comment: @robev Nice to know the backstory. Believe it or not, ArtScroll _did_ (for a time) discontinue the book. I believe within the last two years or so they started to publish it again.